# EntityFramework6 Configuration with WCF Service boundrary

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf, entity-framework-6

I'm attempting to architect a solution involving a WCF service, which calls a dll containing an EntityFramework6 model. When I attempt to unit test the service however, I receive a message:
`Additional information: No connection string named 'SyslogEntities' could be found in the application config file.`

My flow is arranged logically as:

```
SyslogDataSvcTest.dll (app.config has service bindings) -> 
      SyslogDataSvc.svc (web.config has provider and connection string) ->
           LibSyslogData.dll (app.config has providers and connection string)
```

All the code that touches EF is in the libSyslogData.dll. It maps data to upper layer objects internally, and returns them, instead of exposing its own model info, so EF use should be really isolated.

So what am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I got it working well, but in perhaps a weird way. It seems the settings in my app.config were not correctly specified by NuGet when installing the EF and MySql dependencies.

Instead I created an in-code configuration class as described on MSDN here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699

Now that I have this class:

```
public class EFConfiguration : DbConfiguration {
    public EFConfiguration()
    {

        //For some reason this works much better than the app.config.
        //With this defined, upper layer config documents need only specify the "SyslogEntities" Connection string.
        SetExecutionStrategy("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", () => new MySqlExecutionStrategy());
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new MySqlConnectionFactory());
        SetProviderFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySqlClientFactory());
        SetProviderServices("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySqlProviderServices());
    }
}
```

I can leave the specifics of the DB implementation to the datalayer, and only configure the connection string at the upper layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely don't test the actual wcf service (I mean online) based on that exception. I think you are just unit testing the wcf service dlls code. So this would mean the app.config used is from the unit test assembly. Just 1 app.config for runtime for application, having an app.config for a class library does not make sense anyway either.

You need to provide the EF connectionstring that your EF data-access layer is using in your unit test assemblies, as you are doing in your wcf services web.config (since you are not testing the online wcf service). If you want to be totally free of EF references in your unit tests and wcf service configs, you need to override the default constructors for your EF entities and provide the "normal" dbprovider + connectionstring in your app/web configs and create the EF connection string(s) on the fly.

Comment: Thanks! I am debugging with everything in one solution (IIS 8 express for debug), so in retrospect, the unit tests probably are skipping the service hosting, and going straight to the dlls as you suggest. I got it working by adding the connection string (I had tried that before posting to no avail) but also the entity framework provider, provider factory, and connection factory definitions to the unit test app.config. I'm a little surprised it worked since it contains refs to the Mysql libs, but it didn't make me reference the dlls directly.

Comment: oddly enough, it looks like a code based definition worked better. I had created a configuration class before moving the config up to the unit test class, and everything worked, but when I removed the config class, I started getting provider definition errors. I think the config code was incorrectly generated when installing EF and MySql via NuGet. Thanks for your help.